# How can i get Inno setup uninstaller script to remove a service

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

I have a created a installer using inno setup.This setup install my application as a service .when i am trying to uninstall my application it deletes the folder  but i just want it to first search for a particular service and remove it and then procede to delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly you can remove a service in by

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "stop mysrv" ; Flags: runhidden
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "delete mysrv" ; Flags: runhidden
```

Comment: Great tip! I was trying to do this by running a bat file, but was not working.

Comment: That code works fine, but it is executed after the file deletion. How can I execute this code before the file removing tentative?